# Discord.js Minecraft status body is not defined error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Hello im making a discord bot about getting info on minecraft servers.
I'm new here and this is my first post.

```
var request = require("request");
     var mcIP = "IPHERE";
     var mcPort = "PORTHERE";

     var url = "http://mcapi.us/server/status?ip" + mcIP + "&port" +mcPort;

     request(url, function(err,response,body) {
      if(err) msg.channel.send(err);
     });
      body = JSON.parse(body);           
      var status = `Server : ${mcIP} is off`;
      if(body.online) {
      status = `Server : ${mcIP} is on`;
       if(body.players.now){
        status += 'Player count :' + body.players.now;
       }
       else {
         status += 'No one is online.';
       }
    }
msg.channel.send(status);
```

so i got a error its says

```
body is not defined
```

I still dont understand "what is worng"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you are closing off your bracket to early. Because of this, body becomes out of scope. Try this instead

```
request(url, function(err,response,body) {
      if(err) msg.channel.send(err);

      body = JSON.parse(body);           
      var status = `Server : ${mcIP} is off`;
      if(body.online) {
      status = `Server : ${mcIP} is on`;
       if(body.players.now){
        status += 'Player count :' + body.players.now;
       }
       else {
         status += 'No one is online.';
       }
 });
```

Comment: No problem :). Please hit the check mark so others can find this answer